# keep getting ORA-00920: invalid relational operatord

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

keep getting ORA-00920 before v.luggage_capacity...
please help...
I tried using , but it still won't work.
can't figure out what the problem is..

```
create or replace procedure a_ride ( s_state in varchar, d_state in varchar, l_capacity in number, s_capacity in number)
is cursor a_ride IS
select distances.source_state, distances.dest_state, vehicles.luggage_capacity, vehicles.seating_capacity
from distances d, vehicles v
where v.source_state = s_state and d.dest_state = d_state and v.luggage_capacity and v.seating_capacity;enter code here
distances_row a_ride %rowtype;
distances_exist integer;
begin 
distances_exist := distancescheck (s_state, d_state, l_capacity, s_capacity);
If distances_exist >0
then for distances_row in a_ride
loop
dbms_output.put_line ('source_state:' ||distances_row.source_state);
dbms_output.put_line ('dest_state:' ||distances_row.dest_state);
dbms_output.put_line ('luggage_capacity:'||distances_row.luggage_capacity);
dbms_output.put_line ('seating_capacity:'||distances_row.seating_capacity);
dbms_output.put_line ('');
end loop;
lse dbms_output.put_line ('No available ride'); 
end if;
end;
```

Comment: `enter code here`? and what's `lse`?

Comment: Error codes beginning with `ORA` come from Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: @LukStorms That happens if you accidentally type `Ctl-k` in the middle of the code block.

Comment: `and v.luggage_capacity and` This predicate looks like something one would write if `luggage_capacity` were a boolean. If it is numeric, then it should read something like `v.luggage_capacity > 100` (as in 100kg).

Comment: @Barmar Heh, gotta watch out for shortcut habbits I suppose.